# Duplicate entry key on import

Tags: mysql, magento

We’re facing a few problems when trying to update product in Magento at the moment.

What we’ve done so far to eliminate any problems:

- Wiped all products from the database
- Imported all products

Everything was working on site great, then we’ve seen something that needs updating in all of our products so we’re trying to re-import our products to update the existing products.

This is where we’re experiencing some issues:

- Importing existing product with an update produces error:  **SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'**
- This happens on the first record it process

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening? what it the error message actually saying?

Comment: before reimporting, did you delete all entries from the db? seems like old entries are still in the databse.

Comment: No we haven't, we've got a store with thousands of products so deleting everything and starting again isn't an option... we just need to update the tables.

Comment: Well, what kind of queries are you running to update your db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you updating the products? Are you using the product import or dataflow? There is a primary key(s) on the table. The manner in which you are doing the import is trying to add the products and not update them. Since the primary key must be unique, you are trying to put a new record in with an existing primary key. That's what the SQL error is...

Go into the Magento admin, under System > Import/Export > Export. That will get you all the data in the correct format. Make your changes. Then go back and do an import.

On the import screen select 'Replace Complex Data' as the import behavior. I would backup the database first and test it out on a dev environment, but that is the correct way to handle it.